# Convert MySQL query to Laravel models

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

SELECT
clockin.working_day as cdate,
`clockin`.*,
`sch_week`.*,
`user`.`schedule_id`,
`user`.`username`,
(
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(time separator '==')
from
clockin
WHERE
employee_no = user.employee_no
AND working_day = cdate
GROUP by
working_day
) as time
FROM
`user_personal` as user
JOIN clockin
inner join `schedule_week` as `sch_week` on user.schedule_id = sch_week.schedule_id
and week_day = date_format(working_day, '%a')
where
month(working_day) = month(
current_date()
)
GROUP by
user.employee_no,
clockin.working_day
ORDER by
clockin.working_day desc,
user.employee_no;

Comment: `...but there is issue` ... WHAT issue? Add any full error message(s).

Comment: What you have is not using Eloquent - you are using [Laravel query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries).  Eloquent would mean using [Laravel models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent), but your code does not do that.  If you want to use Eloquent, you need to edit your question and show us your models.

Comment: Ok sure I will update question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.